# Python runs ThreadPoolExecutor crosswise when using global

Tags: python, celery, threadpoolexecutor

At my python application I use celery to process long running tasks (many of them). Within one of my tasks I have the following code to upload segments to an S3 Storage, please have a look

```
    if not debug_level['DONT_SEND']:
        count_lock = threading.Lock()
        obj_count = 0

        def __upload(object_path_pair):
            def percentage(part, whole):
                percentage = 100 * int(part) / int(whole)
                return str(percentage) + "%"
            global obj_count
            if obj_count > 0:
                print(f'Uploading segment #{obj_count} to CDN.')
            libera_resource.upload_file(*object_path_pair)
            sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))
            with count_lock:
                if obj_count > 0:
                    print(f' Segment {obj_count} of {len(segment_upload_list)} ({percentage(obj_count, whole=len(segment_upload_list))}) uploaded successfully.')
                obj_count += 1

        def upload_segments(segment_upload_list):
            global obj_count
            obj_count = 0
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
                executor.map(__upload, segment_upload_list)
            print('\n!!! All Segments Uploaded !!!')

        upload_segments(segment_upload_list)
```

In general this is working fine but as soon as the task runs twice at the same time I get strange messages from my print statement

> "print(f' Segment {obj_count} of {len(segment_upload_list)}
> ({percentage(obj_count, whole=len(segment_upload_list))}) uploaded
> successfully.')".

Instead of printing "Segment 34 of 100 (34%) uploaded successfully."
I'll get back (if it runs more then once at the same time)
"Segment 233 of 100 (140%) uploaded successfully."

As you can see the print statement does not make much sense, buy why does it gets printed like that if the task runs twice in the background?
Is this due to the global count I set? And if so, what could be a possible workaround here?
The only thing I can currently imagin is that the global count is used by task call 1 and call 2 at runtime, this then results in a abnormal count which again leads to this ugly output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are running more than one upload thread, you should have a counter for each thread.

One possible solution is to use [thread-local data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) for the counts.

**Edit:**
One important limitation of thread-local data is that it can only be accessed *by its own thread*.

So if you need data from more than one thread, *accessible by another thread* you will have to create a global dictionary of thread specific data.
Some points regarding this dictionary:

- Use a thread's `ident` as the key for the dictionary. Alternatively the `name`, provided you have set it to something descriptive.
- Every thread should *only* update it's own data!
- Every thread may *read* the data from other threads.

That should *mostly* prevent the dictionary being screwed up.
There is however a small chance of a thread being interrupted while it is updating the dictionary.
That would leave the data in an inconsistent state.

Therefore you should probably serialize access to the dictionary through a `Lock`, just to be sure.

**Edit2:**

Small example of a thread that updates a global data structure when it holds a lock.

```
def target(args):
    '''Function to run in a thread.'''
    tid = threading.get_ident()
    running = True
    while running:
        # do stuff...
        # Update the global data structure.
        data_modify_lock.acquire()
        tread_data[tid]['obj_count'] = ...
        # et cetera
        data_modify_lock.release()


data_modify_lock = threading.Lock()
thread_data = {
   2: {'obj_count': 6, 'segment_list': [...]},
   3: {'obj_count': 2, 'segment_list': [...]}
}
```

Comment: can you show an example onto this and how to implement it? If I swap out the global obj_count in favour of a obj_count.x with threading.local() previously initialized the process simply breaks

Comment: @PeterHammi See updated answer.

Comment: A particle example would be awesome. I do not understand how to handle a global dict with thread specific data. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PeterHammi I've added a small example.